# Mailing user groups. ASP.NET MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

How do I send mail to a specific user group (using `Active Directory`)?

As for now I have defined an interface like this:

```
public interface IMailingService {
    void SendMessage(String from, String to, String subject, String body);
}
```

with implementation like this:

```
public class MailingService : IMailingService {
    public void SendMessage(String from, String to, String subject, String body) {
        using(var client = new SmtpClient()) {
            client.SendAsync(
                from: from, 
                recipients: to, 
                subject: subject,
                body: body,
                userToken: "hahaha!"
            );
        }
    }        
}
```

I'm using an smtp client in conjunction with the following configuration.

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="user@domain.com">
            <network host="host" port="25" userName="username" password="password" />
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

But it is hard for me to understand which service should present the behavior, user service which handles `ldap-connections`or a separate service (following the `SOC` principle)?

Any examples?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems like you're asking two different questions - how do you send email to a group via AD, and which service should handle the implementation of SendMessage.  I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: @DavidHoerster when I was asking about mailing it came to me that I'm not sure what service should host the functionality.. That's true there're 2 questions but I can't split them.

Comment: I just have exposed what I have done at the moment (excluding controller injection). But I don't know how do I gain the functionality I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending an email to a user group should work the same way as sending to an individual user.

User groups usually have their own email address and then the Active Directory will handle the rest.

Unless I am misunderstanding your question here.